# Automatically updating view after table update oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have this script in oracle apex database

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
admin_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
admin_email VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
admin_password VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
admin_name VARCHAR2(100),

CONSTRAINT pk_admin PRIMARY KEY (admin_id),
CONSTRAINT unique_admin_email UNIQUE (admin_email)
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
customer_id  NUMBER NOT NULL,
cus_type_id NUMBER,
firstName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR2(50),
phone VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
city_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_customer PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
CONSTRAINT unique_customer_email UNIQUE (email),
CONSTRAINT unique_customer_phone UNIQUE (phone),
CONSTRAINT fk_cus_type_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (cus_type_id) REFERENCES Customer_type     (cus_type_id) on Delete cascade,
CONSTRAINT fk_city_customer FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES cities (city_id) on delete cascade

);

/*USERS VIEW */

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users AS
SELECT admin_id AS user_id,
   admin_name AS user_name,
   'admin' AS user_role
FROM admins

UNION ALL

SELECT customer_id AS user_id,
   firstName AS user_name,
   'customer' AS user_role
FROM customer;

-- Trigger for "admins" table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_after_insert_admins
AFTER INSERT ON admins
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name, user_role)
 VALUES (:new.admin_id, :new.admin_name, 'admin');
END;
 /

-- Trigger for "customer" table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_after_insert_customer
AFTER INSERT ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name, user_role)
  VALUES (:new.customer_id, :new.firstName, 'customer');
END;
```

when i try to insert into the admins table (to check if the users view get updated automatically) i get this error

```
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
ORA-06512: at "WKSP_RSWSP.TR_AFTER_INSERT_ADMINS", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'WKSP_RSWSP.TR_AFTER_INSERT_ADMINS'
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

this is my insert statement

```
INSERT INTO admins (admin_id, admin_email, admin_password, admin_name)
VALUES (ADMIN_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'admin.test@test.com', 'xvyzzzz12', 'admintest');
```

what i'm trying to do is to make add the new row that was inserted into admins to the users view automatically

Comment: A view automatically reflects what's in the underlying table(s) - it's just a pre-defined query. Therefore I'm not sure why you're trying to insert data into a view or why you think this would even be possible?

Comment: You don't need those triggers - this will work fine without them.